# Filtering in pig by concatenating two column

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I have two table in the following format

Table 1: com_Data

### #cc  bb mm#

#### 41  22  2563

#### 42  24  3562

Table 2:

### #name  cid#

#### sasi  41-22-2563

#### soman 42-47-2562

I want to compaine the three column cc bb mm from table 1 and need to filter out all the column from the table 2 which match the combined values

How to filter it in pig

When try to concatenate the three column separated by '-' using pig resulted in error
below is the code which I used

```
a = LOAD 'default.com_data' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
b = foreach a generate concat(cc,'-',bb,'-',mm);
```

How to filter the table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its look like the datatype of cc,bb and mm are numbers. Can you change the datatype to charrarray or bytearray, so that concat will work. Please see the below example

```
input.txt
41 22 2563
42 24 3562
43 46 1234

input1.txt
sasi 41-22-2563
soman 42-47-2562
test 43-46-1234

PigScript:
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (cc:chararray,bb:chararray,mm:chararray);
AA = LOAD 'input1.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (name:chararray,cid:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE CONCAT(cc,'-',bb,'-',mm) as newCid;
C = JOIN AA BY cid,B BY newCid;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE $0,$1;
DUMP D;

Output:
(sasi,41-22-2563)
(test,43-46-1234)
```

Comment: i am loading the data from a table and when i done the above query i am getting an error like `Could not resolve concat using imports`

Comment: from the docs: "The names of Pig Latin functions are case sensitive."

Comment: i created the table with all those field as string and now when i run the query i am getting a result like

`Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.CONCAT as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.`

Comment: @AnasA, Sorry I never used HCatLoader to load my data, so i really don't know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use explicit cast for that.
When you can Loading a file it consider cc, bb and mm as a int value and '-' is a character.

you can write your query like this

```
a = LOAD 'default.com_data' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
b = foreach a generate concat((chararray)cc,'-',(chararray)bb,'-',(chararray)mm);
```

then you can use your filter.